# share huge memory object between gunicorn processes

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am running django app on nginx webserver, running 5 gunicorn workers (aka processes)

i need to initialize large dataset (AI model) into memory, so the API calls can get data from it. the set is around 200MB.

the problem is that if each gunicorn process will init this dataset, then the memory usage (only for this dataset) is 1GB (200mb * 5 processes).

what is the best approach to avoid it? so less memory will be used on my webserver for this dataset?

Comment: Did you try to loading the dataset as a singleton?

Comment: wont help, its between different processes